# Detect success/failure while sharing content using ShareActionProvider

Tags: java, android, android-sharing

I am doing sharing in my application using `ShareActionProvider`. However I can not find a way to validate if sharing was successful or not (failed, user cancelled it at some point, etc.). Is it possible to do this?

I know I could make it easy using `startActivityForResult` but I found out that using `ShareActionProvider` is a recommended way.

Comment: just use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html#setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener) (setOnShareTargetSelectedListener)

Comment: according to documentation it is called upon share method selection - not when content was really shared using chosen method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this?

No.

> I know I could make it easy using startActivityForResult

Usually, that will not work either. That will *only* work for activities *specifically designed* to be called by `startActivityForResult()`, and few `ACTION_SEND`-capable activities are designed that way. [The documentation for `ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) says that there is no output, and therefore few `ACTION_SEND`-capable activities will bother calling `setResult()`.